# Why does invertibility of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ guarantee that every element is a square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

In Serre's arithemetic he claims at the top of page 18 that because $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ we have that every element in the multiplicative group $U_1 = 1 + p\cdot\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a square. Why is this true? The only step I can show is the invertibility of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Using the power series expansion
$$
\frac{1}{1 + p} = 1 - p + p^2 - p^3 + p^4 - \cdots
$$
we can see that
$$
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{p+1}{2}\cdot (1  - p + p^2 - p^3 + p^4 - \cdots) \in \mathbb{Z}_p
$$

Comment: $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ but it is not a square. Something is missing.

Comment: I don't think Serre says that...

Comment: Here is Serre's statement: "...but $U_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$; all the elements of $U_1$ are then squares"

Comment: and $U_1$ is the set of $p$-adic integers $1 + p\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: It's important to note that $U_1$ is a multiplicative group and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an additive group. So squaring in $U_1$ becomes multiplication by $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @carmichael561 thanks. If you want to turn that into an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Oh, and now I finally understood (I think...) what was going on here... :)

Comment: Perhaps the idea is that $U_1$ as a multiplicative group is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as an additive group. The argument about invertibility of two then makes sense.

Comment: Assuming $p>2$ here. $1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, so Hensel's Lemma also implies that all the elements in $U_1$ are squares. That also depends on $2$ being invertible, because the derivative of $x^2-1$ at $x=1$ is...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is an excellent point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$U_1=1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a group under multiplication, which is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p$. The fact that every element of $U_1$ is a square (for $p>2$) then follows from the fact that for every $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ there is some $y\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $x=2y$, and this follows from the fact that $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: And of course for $p\ne2$, the logaritihm furnishes the isomorphism you invoke in your first sentence.

Comment: @Lubin: True, though I was taking that as given since Serre proved it a page or two before the section the OP was referring to.